# I need to remove an attribute from an element after it is clicked with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am a begginer in JavaScript and I have this problem:
HTML code:

```
<textarea class="text_input" cols="40" rows="1" onclick="init_area();"></textarea>
<textarea class="text_input" cols="40" rows="1" onclick="init_area();"></textarea>
```

I want that when a user clicks on this textarea element to remove cols attribute for example. But only for the element that is clicked.
I dont know how to do that.
Can you help, please?

Comment: A tip: `this` in an eventhandler function refers to the element which an event has been attahed to.

Comment: @Teemu: But only if the event was bound *using* JavaScript.  An `onclick` attribute is handled a little differently.  I think he'd have to do: `onclick="init_area(this);"`.  I haven't used `onclick` attributes in forever since they are bad practice.

Comment: I tried :
function init_area() {
 this.removeAttribute("cols");
}

Comment: @RocketHazmat You're right, with inline handlers this-value has to be passed (as well as event object).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this method : **removeAttribute()**

```
<textarea class="text_input" cols="40" rows="1" onclick="init_area();this.removeAttribute('cols'); "></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.removeAttribute(cols) within your function - this refers to the element that the onclick event is attached to as long as init_area() is only called from your text area.

Comment: <textarea class="text_input" cols="40" rows="1" onclick="init_area(this);"></textarea>
and the function
function init_area() {
 this.removeAttribute(cols);
}
setTimeout(init_area,1000);
But I get an error in the console
Uncaught TypeError: this.removeAttribute is not a function
I am lost

Comment: Your function doesn't take any arguments, use `function init_area(el) {el.removeAttribute(...);}`

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<textarea class="text_input" cols="40" rows="1" onclick="init_area(event);"></textarea>
<textarea class="text_input" cols="40" rows="1" onclick="init_area(event);"></textarea>
```

And in your JS file:

```
init_area = function(event) {
  event.target.removeAttribute("cols");
}
```

But you should try to remove the function call from the HTML Element and move it into the JS File:

```
yourElement.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Solution for me to this was Kris solution.
init_area = function(event) {
  event.target.removeAttribute("cols");
}
I understand now how it works, and it work in Chrome. I didnt test it on other browser but thanks so much for your answer